# Custom post type template but

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm looking for the right way to create a template that would render a single instance of my custom post-type.

The trick is that this post type should not be reachable directly (I mean a single item should not be associated to a specific URL). This post type is only meant to be included as a carousel of instances on specific existing page, I guess with the `WP_Query()` and `while ($loop->have_posts())…` methods.

Here is my post type

```
function acme_blog_product_declare() {
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Blog product', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Description …' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-media-document',
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'can_export'            => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'rewrite'               => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'public'                => false
    );
    register_post_type( 'blog_product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'acme_blog_product_declare', 0 );
```

And this is the block where I'd like to render some instances of `blog_product` custom post type.

```
<div class="product-group__body"><?php
    $args = array('post_type'=>'produit_blogueuse');
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    // Which is the template I should create ? (To put a single element's html layout)
    // I want a single element to be rendered on each loog here
    // What should I pass as arguments .. ? :|
    get_template_part( ??, 'blog_product' ); 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?></div>
```

I heard/read about `single-<POST_TYPE_NAME>.php` (but seams to be the full page template), `get_template_part(…)` (don't really know what it is), and «partials» ...

So, which is the right *Wordpress* way to go for this purpose ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: maybe I'm just complicating things and should simply use `single-blog_product.php`  `:/`